# Change home directory with symlink

Tags: macos, ssd

I added an SSD to my system, so now I have a boot drive on the SSD and my home directory on a different volume. I successfully changed the home directory as specified in [Change Users Home Directory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99298/change-users-home-directory). However, this breaks all of the symlinks I've set up for my dotfiles, since things like `.bashrc` which used to point to `/Users/me/.local/dotfiles/.bashrc` are now broken.

My fix was to instead change `/Users/me/` to be a symlink to `/Volumes/Home/Users/me`, and set `/Users/me` to be my home directory. Are there any stability problems with this approach? Will it be noticeably slower than having my home directory actually be `/Volumes/Home/Users/me`?

Answer (score 3):

This approach is quite okay and generally sane. You should verify that Time Machine is still backing up your home directory, following the symlink to the new drive, and not just backing up a reference to your directory.

Comment: Oh! I didn't consider that. I'll definitely check that out once my backup completes, thanks.