# Cannot download anything in Mojave from factory

Tags: macos

I just received today my new iMac with Mojave 14.1 preinstalled.

I have pervasive issues downloading anything.  Downloads get interrupted all the time.

The connection does not seem to be the root cause.  I have a good Internet Fiber connection, browsing is just awesome.  Everything renders fast, including images.

But downloads are a nightmare, a real blocking issue.  For example:

- Nearly no application can be downloaded.  If I try to download Visual Studio Code, Chrome and many other applications it always gets interrupted.
- If I try to download from the Mac Store, downloads start but are eventually reset.  I only was able to download Microsoft Remote Desktop.
- I was able to download Firefox.  If I try to download Chrome from Firefox,  I get the error `/Users/pcondal/Downloads/rEZCkycn.dmg.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.`
- The 10.14.1 update download did not work either (could not be 'verified').  If I click *Update Now* to restart download of 10.14.1, it says `To update, you must restart your Mac`. If I restart, it abends the install and starts again.  So I cannot redownload 14.1.1 because it thinks it already has it and I all can do is restart with a damaged package.

Clearly, this is not the first day with an iMac one dreams on.

What options do I have to try to solve these pervasive download issues?

Comment: There is no need to include the answer in the question. Just answer below (as you already did) and accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Apple offers 90 days of complimentary support and setup assistance so you qualify for free online / phone support to make amends. You've clearly got something that's not even close to happy, so this isn't the on boarding experience that was designed (clearly)

If it were me, I would just boot to recovery and erase and start the setup over. That takes about 15 minutes plus however long it takes to re-download the installer. It's often much harder to determine what went wrong and if you have a new machine, a fresh start will let you know right away if it was just some things that didn't get set up, a poor image of the OS or a very rare case of something not right. Getting Apple involved sooner if you're not sure how to erase would be my winning move if I wasn't super comfortable with recovery mode.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904
- [Reinstall Mac OS X Mountain Lion before selling a Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70625/)
- [Trying to reinstall OS Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264170/)
- [Can I install an older OS X over a newer OS X without restoring from backup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220588/)

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering my own question so that a possible solution has a bit more visibility.  I solved the issue by using Ethernet instead of Wifi.

Comment: While I'm a big proponent of using hard wired connections over WiFi, it would be good to fully diagnose the WiFi issue.  For instance, is it just because your connectivity is poor where your iMac is located?  Is WiFi saturated with other traffic?  Is your WiFi adapter in your new iMac faulty?  If it is your iMac, it would be good to get it fixed before the warranty runs out.  If it's WiFi issues, at least you know that this is something that needs to be sorted out.

Comment: I added the answer regarding alternative connectivity to help others try.  I was giving for granted that Wifi was working well because browsing was really fast in all devices and I am the only Wifi here (house in not very populated area).  Then I noticed that other iOS devices could not download their update via this Wifi connection.  So I suspect that in my case, the router provided by carrier has some issue with Wifi at least on the 5GHz band. The Fiber installation is also new.

Comment: When I disabled the 5GHz band in the router and left only the 2.4 GHz band, the iOS devices could complete the updates.  So in my case the issue was most likely caused by the cheap router provided by my carrier, that does not handle completely well serving two Wifi bands at the same time.