# Tradeoffs between symlinking vs changing path to $HOME

Tags: macos, user-account, system-settings, symlink

I'm moving my user account $HOME to a different drive. The Apple-blessed procedure is outlined [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99299/23270).

An alternative would be just to symlink from the old to the new location. Are there any functionally significant differences or tradeoffs between the two approaches? Would (for example) Time Machine handle both the same? Anything else anyone can think of?